# Use connectionstring in WebJob on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

Is there an easy way to share connection string between website and WebJob on Azure?
The only way I found already is to read web.config from console application, but it doesn't look good for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Azure website and WebJob are sharing the application settings/connection strings set on the Azure portal.
So assuming you're using a .NET console application as a WebJob, just use `ConfigurationManager` to get your connection string (to help test it, just have your app.config have the same connection string key).

If you're not using .NET console application, the connection strings are in the environment so you can just query for them.

Comment: How can I query them? For example in powershell?

Comment: For powershell go to the following url: https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell it will give you a powershell shell to your site which can help you experiment, there try the following command: `gi env:*CONN*` it'll give you all your connection strings.

Comment: Just for info, for console app, you'd also need to upload the {app}.exe.config file along with the exe in the zip to have app-settings / connection-strings replaced dynamically.

Comment: @Amit Any chance you can write up a short program that shows how share the connection strings and get the db context inside of the program?

Comment: @Jed to get the connection string use: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONNECTION_STRING_NAME"]`, to use it depends on the component using it but no specific changes needed for WebJobs

Comment: If i use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MY_CONNECTION_STRING"]`  i'm getting `Cannot open database "MyDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
 Login failed for user 'myuser'`

Comment: Seems like an invalid (user login) connection string, try using it locally and see if it works

Comment: I am not able to understand about connection string, Is it same like we are using in web.config then what will be the datasource, username and password for this connection string. Please explain I am new with webjob.