# SQL Database access from a WebJob in Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

I plan to use WebJobs as a lightweight substitute for NServiceBus but wanted to first verify that routine SQL Azure Database queries can be made from a triggered WebJob handler? My database access will be through EntityFrameworks.

This SO thread indicates that WebJobs does not support SQL Database but I hope this just means that SQL Database cannot be used as a triggering mechanism for a WebJob handler?

[Azure Web Job - How to connect to an Azure MS SQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758043/azure-web-job-how-to-connect-to-an-azure-ms-sql-database)

I have not found a WebJob sample that issues SQL Database queries but since a WebJob has access to the same app config as the main WebSite I assume database connection details can be made available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Webjobs are any executable that can run on Azure (so .NET programs will run fine).  The **triggering mechanism is specific and CANNOT** utilize SQL Azure but **you can run SQL Azure** in your executable code **WITHIN the webjob itself**.

For Example, this webjob waits for the message 'web-jobs-testing-sql' on 'testwebjobsqueue' before executing the query on the SQL Azure database and writing the results to the text file in the configured storage container:

```
namespace AzureWebJobs
{
    class AzureSqlTest
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            JobHost host = new JobHost();
            host.RunAndBlock(); 
        }

        public static void SyndicateFiles([QueueInput("testwebjobsqueue")] string inputText, 
                            [BlobOutput("temp/WebJobs-log.txt")]TextWriter writer)
        {
            if (!inputText.StartsWith("web-jobs-testing-"))  
                return;

            writer.WriteLine(String.Format("Starting to do processing for " + inputText + " at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()));
            string storageContainerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageContainerNameTemp"].ToLower();

            AzureStorageUtils.ConfigureStorage(storageContainerName);

            SQLTest sqlTest = new SQLTest();
            sqlTest.RunSqlQuery(inputText, writer);
            writer.WriteLine(String.Format("Syndication Finished at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()));
        }
    }


    class SQLTest
    {
        public SQLTest()
        {

        }

        public void RunSqlQuery(string queueMessage, TextWriter writer)
        {
            if (queueMessage == "web-jobs-testing-sql")
            {
                string connectionString = "Server=tcp:YourDatabaseServerName.database.windows.net,1433;Database=YourDatabaseName;User ID=YourSQLAzureUserID;Password=YourStrongPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;";
                SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();


                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

                sqlConnection1.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                sqlConnection1.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course it would be best to store your connection string, storage container names, etc. in the configuration settings of your website hosting the webjob (you can do this in the 'app settings' and 'connection strings' sections of the 'configure tab' in the azure portal so you don't have any settings in files accessible on the website).

Comment: Thank you for the extensive code example, I was hoping for positive confirmation because I want to get a pilot example of my first Azure app running without the additional burden of configuring web and worker roles (plus associated costs). I should not be critical of the docs since WebJobs is in beta but I feel there is too much emphasis demonstrating how to configure WebJobs rather than how to invoke and what can be done within a WebJob.

Comment: I agree but there are a few decent examples around. The one I posted is based on one of my production jobs (without the SQL). Right now I'm just keeping things simple while in preview and until more functionality is added but what is there will get the job done for now. I'll dig up a few more links for you and post here later.

Comment: is there a way to know the IP address of the machine running the web job? The reason is that I'm planning to access a SQL Azure database that is protected IP filtering.

Comment: @Shankar Yes, the WebJobs are run on your Azure Web App instance, so assuming you are not using shared instances or auto-scaling, you can find the IP adresses under Properties->Outbound IP Addresses.

Answer (score 1):

We do not have a triggers for SqlAzure yet. It is something we would consider opening up by way of opening up extensibility for allowing you to Trigger functions based on different events such as SQL Azure, File System watchers etc.
You can share the ConnectionString that you can share between your site and webjob. The following post captures this [Use connectionstring in WebJob on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791383/use-connectionstring-in-webjob-on-azure)

Comment: This is a must have functionality. I also need watch for SqlAzure table called Queue. If some row is inserted into this table I need to run this WebJob. Simple way to implement this is for example to create method Run inside AzureWebJob which will be called every 1min or some time interval for example in case of continues Azure Web Job. This way I can implement logic inside SQLAzure myself.

Comment: quite an old topic, but for others. You should use Storage Queues for this. 
Find more information in the Microsoft docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to

if processing fails, it will be retried 5 times by default.
if it's not successful the message is moved to the poison queue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/visual-studio/vs-storage-webjobs-getting-started-queues#automatic-poison-message-handling