# How to use EF Repository Pattern to update Database from Azure Web Job?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject, repository-pattern, azure-webjobs

What is the proper way to update SQL Azure using Entity Framework from **Azure Web Job** ?

I only able to found a post [SQL Azure using Azure Web Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941001/sql-database-access-from-a-webjob-in-azure)

But above solution using *SQL Client* not through *Entity Framework* !!!

can bellow code run properly under **Azure Web Job**

```
public void DoSomething([TimerTrigger("*/5 *  * * * *")] TimerInfo timer, TextWriter log)
        {
            try
            {

                var tempdetails = _sampleRepository.SearchFor(x=> DateTime.UtcNow > x.DateTo);

                foreach (var detail in tempdetails)
                {
                    if (detail.ID == 2)
                    {
                        detail.ID = 5;
                    }
                    _sampleRepository.Update(detail);
                }

                 _unitOfWork.Commit();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

**Ninject Binding**

```
public class NinjectBindings : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            //Register Context
            Kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf();
            Kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>();

            //Register Repository
            Kernel.Bind(x => x
           .FromAssemblyContaining<MyDbContext>()
           .SelectAllClasses()
           .InheritedFrom(typeof(IRepository<>))
           .BindDefaultInterface());

        }
    }
```

**Program.CS**

```
static void Main()
        {
            using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectBindings()))
            {
                var config = new JobHostConfiguration()
                {
                    JobActivator = new NinjectJobActivator(kernel)
                };

                if (config.IsDevelopment)
                {
                    config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
                }

                config.UseTimers();

                var host = new JobHost(config);
                host.RunAndBlock(); 
            }
        }
```

## **App.Config**

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="" />
    <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="" />
    <add name="EFContext" connectionString="Server=xxxx,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;....;User
    ID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxx;...;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection
    Timeout=30;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

**"Azure Portal Setting to Run Web Job"**

> As discussed with  [ **MS Support** ] , after we added the
>   **AzureWebJobsStorage** and **AzureWebJobDashboard** connection strings as the **Application settings blade** in Azure Portal the web-job started to work
>   without the exception.

How To find out **Root cause** of the bellow issue

**[ Working Code - Update Database]**

```
var tempdetails = _myRepository.SearchFor(condifiotn);

if(tempdetails != null)
{
    foreach (var detail in tempdetails)
    {
      _unitOfWork.GetContext.Entry(detail).State = EntityState.Detached;

       //Do Some Modification
       detail.Name = "Test";

     _unitOfWork.GetContext.Entry(detail).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    //Save Changes
     _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

**[ Not Working Code - Unable to update database]**

```
var tempdetails = _myRepository.SearchFor(condifiotn);

if(tempdetails != null)
{
    foreach (var detail in tempdetails)
    {            
       //Do Some Modification
       detail.Name = "Test";

     _myRepository.Update(detail);
    }

    //Save Changes
     _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

**Update Method**

```
 public void Update(E entity)
        {

            //_dbSet.Attach(entity);
            UnitOfWork.GetContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

Comment: Configure your EF context with the appropriate connection string (there's numerous ways to do so).  It's no different than any other db, really.

Comment: Why do you want to use entity framework?

Comment: I just I want to reuse the code ( Repository Pattern)

Comment: @Dymeng : I updated my post still getting error. Job is in "Pending Restart" state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ninject binding in `Singleton Scope` do the job as exception. I know this is **not the best solution**. Waiting for best ans.  If some how I configure Ninject in **Call Scope**.

**//Register Context**

```
    Kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
    Kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().InSingletonScope();
```

**[** using `InSingletonScope` bellow code working as expected **]**

```
var tempdetails = _myRepository.SearchFor(condifiotn);

if(tempdetails != null)
{
    foreach (var detail in tempdetails)
    {            
       //Do Some Modification
       detail.Name = "Test";

     _myRepository.Update(detail);
    }

    //Save Changes
     _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I followed this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770156/Understanding-Repository-and-Unit-of-Work-Pattern) to implement my Repository and Unit of Work Pattern in my Azure Web Jobs. You could follow the code snippet below to check your code.

**NinjectBindings:**

```
public class NinjectBindings : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<DbContext>().ToMethod(ctx=> {
            return new BruceDbContext();
        });
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

**BruceDbContext:**

```
public class BruceDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BruceDbContext()
        : base("name=brucedbcontext")
    {
    }

    public BruceDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }

    //...
}
```

**UnitOfWork:**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    public UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public IRepository<Author> AuthorRepository =>
       new GenericRepository<Author>(_dbContext);

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _dbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Functions.cs**

```
public class Functions
{
    private static IUnitOfWork _iUnitOfWork;
    public Functions(IUnitOfWork iUnitOfWork)
    {
        _iUnitOfWork = iUnitOfWork;
    }

    public void DoSomething([TimerTrigger("*/30 *  * * * *")] TimerInfo timer, TextWriter log)
    {
        _iUnitOfWork.AuthorRepository.Add(new Author()
        {
            Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        });
        _iUnitOfWork.Commit();

        var allRecords=_iUnitOfWork.AuthorRepository.GetAll().ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allRecords));
    }
}
```

**Note:** Since you are using `TimerTrigger`, you need to call the `config.UseTimers();` before constructing the `JobHost`. Additionally, you could debug your webjob locally to find the detailed error. Or you could update your question and provide more detailed errors (e.g. ex.StackTrace) for us to narrow this issue.

Comment: why you write  `private static IUnitOfWork _iUnitOfWork;` as static ?. I also update my post

Comment: Will tell me what is issue with the abode code. It is running without any error. But not updating database & but able to fetch data from database.